# How to process Array of JSON Stream Response in node.js server streaming http resquest

Tags: node.js, http, node-fetch, jsonstream

The stream response is form of

```
[{
  "id":0,
  "name":name0
}
,
{
  "id":1,
  "name":name1
}
]
```

if I use `node-fetch` stream feature to fetch, iterate the response.body, the chunk data is cut the object randomly. And I can't parse on it. I guess `node-fetch` not support array of json, and can't recognize `[`, `]`.

How to process the streaming array of json? Or any other 3rd party library?
sample code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function main() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  try {
    for await (const chunk of response.body) {
      console.log('----start')
      console.dir(JSON.parse(chunk.toString()));
      console.log('----end')}
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  }
}

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach to stream parse an external JSON source is to combine `node-fetch` with `stream-json` to parse the incoming data regardless of how the (string) data is chunked.

```js
import util from "util";
import stream from "stream";
import StreamArray from "stream-json/streamers/StreamArray.js";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const response = await fetch(url);

await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(
  response.body,
  StreamArray.withParser(),
  async function( parsedArrayEntriesIterable ){
    for await (const {key: arrIndex, value: arrElem} of parsedArrayEntriesIterable) {
      console.log("Parsed array element:", arrElem);
    }
  }
)
```

*`stream.pipeline()` with `async function` require NodeJS >= v13.10*